# Mapping values to text box in maximo asset management

Tags: maximo

I tried to map a text box with list of values to select from.
I added an Alphanumeric Domain (ALN) and assigned it to the related attribute in database configuration.
From App Designer, I defined VALUELIST lookup for the text box.
When I click on arrows to select from the list, I got Invalid Binding.
I noticed that the database configuration is in 'to be changed' status.

How can I apply the changes, or what is the issue in what I did?

Comment: Possible typo: "ANL" should be "ALN". lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the database in Admin mode and select Actions -> Apply Configuration Changes similar to discussed [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/changing-length-and-scale-attribute-maximo)